# Prolog: change depthfirst search to bredth first search

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have an assignment for prolog where i'm on the final step but i just can't finish it. We have a given forward planner which is depth first and have to modify said planner so it is breadth first. We are given an example for a breadth first search, so we can implement that in the code:

```
% bfs(+initial_state, ?goal_state, ?solution)
bfs(X,Y,P) :-
    bfs_b(Y,[n(X,[])],[],R),
    reverse(R,P).

% bfs_b(?goal_state, +open_list, +closed_list, -reversed_solution)
bfs_b(Y,[n(Y,P)|_],_,P).
bfs_b(Y,[n(S,Pl1)|Ns],C,P) :-
    findall(n(S1,[A|P1]),
            (s(S,S1,A), \+ member(S1,C)),
            Es),9
    append(Ns,Es,O),
    bfs_b(Y,O,[S|C],P).

s(a,b,go(a,b)).
s(b,a,go(b,a)).
s(a,c,go(a,c)).
s(c,a,go(c,a)).
s(b,d,go(b,d)).
s(d,b,go(d,b)).
s(b,e,go(b,e)).
s(e,b,go(e,b)).
s(c,e,go(c,e)).
s(e,c,go(e,c)).
s(d,f,go(d,f)).
s(f,d,go(f,d)).
s(d,g,go(d,g)).
s(g,d,go(g,d)).
s(e,g,go(e,g)).
s(g,e,go(g,e)).
```

I know that the recursive predicate bfs_b should be implemented in the original code. The code we have for the forward planner is:

```
fp(S,G,P) :- 
    list_to_set(S,SS),
    list_to_set(G,GS),
    fp(SS,GS,[],R),
    reverse(R,P).


% fp(+StateSet,+GoalsSet,+Operators,-Plan)
fp(S,G,P,P) :- holds(G,S).
fp(S,G,Os,P) :-
    pop(O,Pre,A,D),
    holds(Pre,S),
    \+ member(O,Os),
    apply(S,A,D,S1),
    fp(S1,G,[O|Os],P).

% holds(+Goals,+State): the goals (or preconditions) Goals hold in State
holds([],_).
holds([Pre|Ps],S) :- 
    select(Pre,S,S1), 
    holds(Ps,S1).

% apply(+State,+AddList,+DeleteList,-NewState): NewState is the result of updating State with AddList and DeleteList
apply(S,A,D,S1) :-
    subtract(S,D,S2),
    union(A,S2,S1).

pop(move(X,Y),
    [block(X),block(Y),on(X,Z),
     clear(X),clear(Y)],
    [clear(Z),on(X,Y)],
    [clear(Y),on(X,Z)]).

pop(move_to_table(X),
    [block(X),block(Y),on(X,Y),clear(X)],
    [on(X,table),clear(Y)],
    [on(X,Y)]).
```

I know i have to change the fp/4 predicate according to the bfs_b predicate, but i just don't know how... If someone could help me out, that would be greatly appreciated! This is the final step in my assignment so help would be awesome!

Comment: Where is your depth first planner? BTW iterative deepening is probably an option, too

Comment: do you understand the working of `cons( A, X, [A | X] ).` and `snoc( A, X, Z, W ) :- Z = [A | W].`? with the latter you don't need to ever use `append`, either.

Comment: @false I have to use a breadth first planner. I thought the depth first planner was already in the forward planner, the second piece of code i posted.

Comment: @WillNess I don't really actually. That piece of code was provided to us and we had to edit that.

Comment: in depth first strategy you have a LIFO stack as your `GoalsSet` agenda. you pop the head off the stack to find what to do next, do it, then add *next-to-do* items to the stack's start. in breadth first strategy you use FIFO queue instead, where you add *next-to-do* items to the queue's *end*. `cons` does the first, `snoc` does the second. can you see the `pop` and the `cons` bits in your `fp/4`? you need to replace them with the `pop` and `snoc` bits instead. e.g. with `X = [1,2,3 | Z], snoc( 4, X, Z, W).` what is `X` now? (also, `X` in `snoc` isn't used, so can be removed from arguments).

Comment: so then, it should be defined as `snoc( A, [A | W], W).`, and the call is `X = [1,2,3 | Z], snoc( 4, Z, W).`.